# DBeaver connection is closed MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, timeout, export, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver to connect to my MS SQL database hosted in local. I try to export my tables as CSV files. In the case where the query is rather big (40k rows which takes a couple of minutes) the export gets stopped with the message

> "SQL Error: The connection is closed".

I kept the default parameters for dbeaver database connection, and my SQL server timeout is the default one (10 minutes, which is more than it takes to trigger the error)

Any idea where it might come from?

Comment: You should get all data from SQL then close connection as fast as possible first. After that, you do something based on your data.

Comment: This is not an option as I need to extract images from binary fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, the value of `binary` is extremely large and weight. So that takes much time to transfer via the network. That's the reason why you're getting error. In my opinion,

1. You should split your query into multiple time to fetch data (How about 1k records in each time).
2. Just get the exactly items that you need (where condition or the columns that you need instead of all)

Comment: I get the point but I know I've been able to do it in the past, with a lot amount of binary fields. Anyway, I'll proceed as you advice thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every database driver allows to configure the `connectTimeout`, a parameter that declares for how long the client (dbeaver) will wait before deciding something went wrong.

You can change this parameter right-clicking on the name of the server, choosing `Edit Connection`, then clicking on the `Driver properties` tab and searching for the `connectTimeout`parameter (or something equivalent). Increase the value you found there.

I had this problem with PostgreSQL 13, found a connectTimeout = 20ms and increased it to 200ms to overcome the issue.

An old MySQL driver showed a `connectTimeout = 20000`, most probably in nanoseconds.